# Remove syntax from contract exceptions

Tags: .net, code-contracts

When the following contract is violated:

```
Contract.Requires<CustomException>(arg1 != null, "arg1 cannot be null");
```

the message in `CustomException.Message` becomes:  **Precondition failed: arg1 != null  arg1 cannot be null**. In this situation, how can I prevent code contracts from adding "**Precondition failed: arg1 != null**" to `CustomException.Message`?

My assembly is using code contract's "standard contract requires" mode (usage 2 in section 5.1 of [code contract's user manual](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/userdoc.pdf)) because I want to use contracts for argument validation on public methods in the release build, thus the reason I'm using `Contract.Requires<T>` (with the type parameter). In this situation I don't seem to have access to my "arg1 cannot be null" message by itself. I do not wish to try to remove "Precondition failed etc." using string manipulations.

I know that if I instead throw a `ContractException` (using the non-generic `Contract.Requires`) I can use reflection to get my message from `ContractException.UserMessage`. But I don't believe these contracts will work when using "standard contract requires" mode, and anyway I won't be able to globally catch these errors.

Comment: if u can throw ur own exception, why not throw the same exception but with message as whatever u like?

Comment: I'd like to leverage code contracts as much as possible without duplicating the validation logic in if..then statements. Since code contracts provides support for throwing exceptions from public methods, I'm (naively) hoping they provided a way to do what I'm asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Code Contracts User Manual](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/userdoc.pdf) (section 5.1.2 page 21) implies this is the expected behaviour:

> RequiresExn(...) is intended to be used with tool support, meaning
>   that they are inherited in all builds and the **message strings are
>   generated automatically to include the failing condition**

It doesn't mention about being to override the automatically generated messages, so I would assume one cannot. However, as a work-around one could create a custom contract runtime class (see section 7, and in particular section 7.7 of the user manual) that rewrites `Requires<Ex>` so that it sets `Exception.Message` as required.

Comment: It should be noted that the exceptions that are being thrown are only meant to be seen by developers using your code. In other words, "end users" should _never_ see these exceptions because, presumably, developers using your code will have met all the preconditions (thus preventing the exception in the first place) or handle the exception appropriately. And this is precisely the benefit of using Code Contracts--ensuring callers use your code the way you expect them to so that you can guarantee to callers that your code will work as expected (i.e. no exceptions).